# Margin collapse not working

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create some layout but I have a problem. I know margin collapse concept so 
I used this html code

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>    
<div>
```

this is my css code

```css
.container{
  width:1080px;
  margin:0 auto;
  background:red;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.left{
   background:yellow;
   width:510px;
   height:200px;
   float:left;
   margin:20px;
}

.right{
   background:blue;
   width:510px;
   height:200px;
   float:right;
   margin:20px;
}
```

but my code is not working. I have above output but I want to get two div inline   http://jsfiddle.net/Cp2Bq/

So i want to know why margin collapse is not working in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So i want to know why margin collapse is not working in my code.

This happens because they are not in the normal flow.
The specification says this:

> Two or more adjoining vertical margins of block boxes in the normal
>   flow collapse

And also, as can be seen in this [specification for floats](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#floats):

> Since a float is not in the flow, non-positioned block boxes created
>   before and after the float box flow vertically as if the float didn't
>   exist.

Comment: Hi, Andrei :) Thank you for your answer. It's helpful to me.